# How to speed up Java applications?

Tags: java

I need to use Java for a desktop application. I heard that there are many tools that compile java natively, is this true? does these tools compile java program into machine code?

THank you!

Comment: Are you actually having performance problems with your Java application, or did you just hear somebody say "Java is slow"? All modern JVMs use JIT compilers to compile code natively at runtime.

Comment: @GregHewgill, exactly I heard that MANY developers say "java is slow", so compile it to native machine code maybe improve a lot the performance of the application.

Comment: Java is not slow! That was partially true with VERY old Java versions. For cross-language benchmarks: http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/ and http://shootout.alioth.debian.org/u32/which-programming-languages-are-fastest.php . BUT: Usually it's NOT the programming language with makes a fast program a fast one or a slow program a slow one.

Comment: Some of us have been writing desktop apps for Java for years. It works fine. Relax!

Answer (score 7):

Since the (Sun/Oracle) Java VM has a good JIT (just-in-time) compiler, you don't have to compile your Java program to machine code yourself. The compiler will do that on the fly when it's necessary.

So: Speed up your Java programs just as every other program:

- reduce algorithmic complexity
- exploit parallelism
- compute at the right moment
- find and remove bottlenecks
- ...

Since Java is a garbage collected language, there is one important point to more speed: *reduce allocations*! Reducing allocations will help you at least twice: The allocation itself isn't done and the garbage collector will have to do less work (which will save time).

Comment: yes you are right, but if I can compile ONE time the application without compile it forever on the fly i think it's better, no?

Comment: @Dail: No. The JIT has a lot of information about the actual code paths that are used at runtime, so it can optimize better than statically compiled code can. It doesn't *always* do better, but it doesn't always do worse, either. Just-in-time compilation is not "compiling it forever on the fly".

Comment: @Dail, here's an example: if you have an `if/else` statement, and at runtime the `else` case is much more common than the `if` case, then the JIT can prioritize the much more common case.  Static compiling can't see which case is actually more common in practice, so it has to just guess.  That's an oversimplification, but hopefully it should give you some idea why JIT has advantages over static compilation.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with the others that compiling to machine code does not make much sense: mind that C free/malloc have same or higher costs than Java new/garbage collection.

The NetBeans IDE comes with a built-in Profiler; so you could profile your application in that IDE to find bottlenecks.

Comment: Yes I Like NetBeans sooo much! but I don't understand WHY if you keep 100 developers 85% say "java is slow". It worries me if I have to release a software

Comment: <Rant>I think I wouldn't actually call most of your "85%" "developers". That's ridiculous, I'd bet a good Java programmer could write faster Java code for any problem than they could in whatever language they want to.</Rant>

Comment: @Dail having been in the same spot a couple of times (thinking of a C++ alternative), profiling often showed a bottleneck, like XML processing. And isn't it that 5% of the code makes up 95% of the time? I hope you're satisfied with the answer of Johannes Weiß, it is good.

Answer (score 1):

are you coding the app or it's someone's else?

It looks you're trying to run an java app that is slow. Try increasing the memory when running it. You can change the shell script specifying these params:
java -Xms64m -Xmx512m

Comment: many developers are advice to me to use C# instead of JAVA (for windows application) I don't know if there are C# vs JAVA benchmarks, but noone advice me Java.... I Like it because I also use Netbeans to develop the GUI.

Comment: The technology of Java (the Java VM) and C# (the CLR) are very much the same... They VM models are both stack machines and the make great use of JIT compiling...

Comment: What kind of application you want to develop? Depending on the type, the speed isn't the main feature you need to focus. Do you already know Java or C#? I would simply choose Java because I already know how to develop for it.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use Java for a desktop application. I heard that there are
>   many tools that compile java natively, is this true? does these tools
>   compile java program into machine code?

Such programs do exist, but may come with tradeoffs when using some of the more dynamic capabilities of the Java platform like you may lose the ability to load new classes at runtime. The JVM may have a slow start up, but it's plenty fast enough once it gets going.

That said, one solution that I didn't see anyone mention here is to replace code written in Swing with [SWT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Widget_Toolkit). The SWT toolkit uses native code underneath.